# How to display the busiest hour of the day (most views/rows) per category in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions, analysis

I'm working on an imaginary dataset (https://github.com/Codecademy/datasets/tree/master/twitch)
regarding Twitch and trying to figure out what the busiest hour of the day is per streamed game (via the "stream.csv" table).

Thereby, I am using:

```
strftime(format, column)
```

to strip the hour of the timestamp.

I tried using:

```
SELECT strftime('%H', time), game, MAX(COUNT(*))
FROM stream
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 3;
```

but SQL does not allow for double aggregations.

How can I still display at what hour of the day each game is streamed/viewed most?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT strftime('%H', time), game, COUNT(*),
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY game ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM stream
      GROUP BY 1, 2
     ) s
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```